# Css styling to specific number of child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have one table, I want to apply css to 5th number of child then 10th number of child the 15th, 20th and so on so that 1st 5 rows looks to be one section then another 5 rows looks different section. What should I do for this. I have below mentioned code.

```css
table{
  background:#fff;
  width:100%
}
td{
  padding:5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(5) td{border-bottom:1px solid red}
table tr:nth-child(10) td{border-bottom:1px solid red}
```

```html
<table colspan="0" celspacing="0">
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>2232</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In my local code rows are coming dynamically and I don't know how many rows will come so I want to apply css to 5th multiple of child using css. Please help.

Comment: Use `:nth-child(5n)`. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. The multiplicy is 10, so for each 10 element you style **only 5** (the last ones from 6 to 10 or the first ones from 1 to 5). With this configuration you will have them different 5 by 5.

```css
table {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr:nth-child(10n+6) td,
table tr:nth-child(10n+7) td,
table tr:nth-child(10n+8) td,
table tr:nth-child(10n+9) td,
table tr:nth-child(10n+10) td {
  background: #f2f2f5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table colspan="0" celspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2232</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is helpful for me. :)

Comment: This should be reduced to a single set of rules with multiple selectors separated with commas. [Don't repeat yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/17bqtx7h/1/).

Comment: @Phylogenesis i know :) at the start i was making different styles to each one so we can better understand the incrementation, then i decided no and kept them separate ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make your css rule just

```
table tr:nth-child(5n) td{border-bottom:1px solid red}
```